# I cannot use vsliveshare even after being accepted

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been accepted to the private Beta of VS Live Share.
If I now try to start a live share session, it says, that I have not been accepted.

I also tried to log out and in again with no changes.

Do you know, what to do?

Comment: Use the support and reporting defined in the vsliveshare guidance. Troubleshooting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/troubleshooting feedback: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/support

Comment: It's a support question for a beta product which has a number of support options available.

Comment: Okay thanks. I just found a link where it said that i had to report it here. Ill try the links.